# Different results from google: curl vs. browser

Tags: curl, command-line

I stumbled onto [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1617152/using-google-as-a-dictionary-lookup-via-bash-how-can-one-grab-the-first-definit) cool Stack Overflow question today and wanted to use the idea as a command line spell checker or dictionary (it would be nice to not have to go from shell to browser and back, but still use the expansive google hive mind-- case in point, I just googled "hivemind" to find out that it is, in fact, two words).

But when I use `curl` I get a different result than with chrome and firefox (even when the agent string is set with `-A 'Mozilla/4.0'`. Specifically, the page it fetches **is stripped of the definitions** that appear at the top.

Now, I'm guessing that it isn't in google's best interest to let us [harvest and present their hard work without attribution](http://bing.com), but I wanted to ask if there is a workaround.

Has anyone else tried to build little command line tools that "call" google?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Could you show the full request?

Comment: `curl -s -A 'Mozilla/4.0' 'https://www.google.com/search?ie=UTF-8&q=define+car'`